# Batch Insertions Using Prepared Statements in Jdbc with Mysql are very slow

Tags: java, mysql

Batch Insertions Using Prepared Statements in Jdbc with Mysql are dead slow
I am trying to Insert 300 Milion Records. The record is split into 29 tables
I tried with 2000 and 1000 records per batch the time take for insertion are 20 and 10 mins respectively
only one table has 20 columns remaining all table will have columns from 3 to 6

Java Code reading 10000 rows in 5 sec but batch Insertions are taking 90 mins of time

I am Working on Windows 7 with 4gb of ram

### My Mysql my.ini configuration is

```
[client]

port=3306

[mysql]

default-character-set=latin1

[mysqld]

max_allowed_packet=100M
wait_timeout=3000

port=3306

basedir="C:/Program Files (x86)/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/"

datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.1/Data/"

default-character-set=latin1

default-storage-engine=INNODB

sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

max_connections=100

query_cache_size=0

table_cache=256

tmp_table_size=33M

thread_cache_size=8

myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G

myisam_sort_buffer_size=66M

key_buffer_size=53M

read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K

sort_buffer_size=256K

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size=3M

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1

innodb_log_buffer_size=2M

innodb_buffer_pool_size=206M

innodb_log_file_size=52M

innodb_thread_concurrency=10
```

Comment: Have you got any indexes on those tables?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to `DROP` all of the tables' indexes, `INSERT` the rows, and then recreate the indexes.  A database can insert data much faster if it doesn't need to update indexes for each row inserted.  And an index can be created from scratch faster than by building it with a "random" sequence of inserts.

It may also improve things if you can sort the rows of the respective tables into primary key order, and insert them in that order.

Finally, batching is a trade-off between the costs of lots of little requests and the costs of doing large / long transactions.  Try experimenting with batch sizes that are smaller and large than those you are currently using.

Comment: are you suggesting to drop all the primary keys also

Comment: I drooped all the Indexes except for the primary keys and tested the code then I posted it

Comment: Ummm ... either drop them, or sort into primary key order.

Comment: I dont think dropping primary key Index is nedded.. if I drop it mysql will create another Index for those tables can you see the my.ini conf and suggest me for any performance tuning...